# how to create OHLC from the data for 5mins duration?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to create a 5 minute OHLC for the data below

```
var data = [{
    "tid": 283945,
    "date": 1384934366,
    "amount": "0.08180000",
    "price": "501.30"
}, {
    "tid": 283947,
    "date": 1384934066,
    "amount": "0.06110000",
    "price": "490.66"
},
...
];
```

The link to piece of code which i had found from one of the threads here that creates OHLC for the day  is https://jsfiddle.net/mg9v89r2/

also i would like to know if there are any frameworks in nodejs to create OHLC for different intervals as in 5mins/30mins/hourly etc

Comment: You can use something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ohlc-aggregator